# Classify strings having centers already found in python?

Tags: classification, clustering, python

On StackOverflow suggested me to ask this question here. I'll copy it.

I have a list of binary strings and two center strings which are not in the list. I would like to classify that list around the center strings in order to create two clusters. A string of the list will be assigned to the cluster whose center is nearest to that string (hamming distance as metric). I've seen that there are alghoritms like Neighbours Classifier, k-medoids, Affinity propagation, but all these procedure calculate centroids on their own; I have to use my center strings instead.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, Stack Overflow was wrong to send you here, because your problem requires no statistics or inference. Just loop through your list of strings and compute the Hamming distance of each from your two "center strings", then assign it to the group with the closer center string.